# Can i W PSU on 0660W UPSrun 60

Tags: graphics-card, power, ups

Is 600 watt Power supply takes more input voltage than 350 watt power supply?.

Comment: You need to give more information about the UPS. You should be OK.

Comment: If this is the only device on the UPS and the wattage is within tolerance limits, I don't see why not. Keep in mind that the PC will hardly ever use the peak power like, ever, so I'd say you're generally safe.

Comment: The critical thing is whether the 660 is watts or VA. If it's watts, it should be fine if the computer is the only device plugged into the UPS.  Your monitor could put it over the UPS rating if the computer is actually using the full power of the PSU at the time, in which case the overload would shut down the UPS when you need it.  If you don't have the monitor on battery backup, it would shut off on power loss, but you could use software to shut down the computer gracefully (typically comes with the UPS).  If the 660 is VA, your computer will likely overload the UPS and cause it to shut down.

Comment: its 1000 V A and 660 W and i am using LCD.When i use computer normally (watching movies etc), it doesn't reboot on power failure.When i am playing games (like G T A iv ).its reboots when power goes down.

Comment: You edited your question and now the title is gibberish and it isn't clear what you are asking.  Your line voltage is standard and doesn't change.  Any power supply designed for that standard will use that voltage.  More power translates to more current.  Any power supply will take in a little more power than what it puts out for the computer because it isn't 100% efficient.  A 600 watt power supply is capable of putting out more power than a 350 watt power supply without being damaged.  What it actually puts out (within its limitations), is determined by the load the computer places on it.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to check the specifications for the particular power supply to see what input voltage range it takes.